How to control window variable
I open the popup window like this,I want to keep this as global object, so put this in window.myWin variable
it works well, at first load the id=test then popup is replaced by id=test2
window.myWin = window.open(`http://localhost:8024/?id=test`,"_blank",'status=yes,width=500,height=500');
console.log(window.myWin); // logpoint1
window.myWin.location.href = `http://localhost:8024/?id=test2`;// it works.

Now after some mouse control of user.
then do this again,
console.log(window.myWin);// logpoint2
window.myWin.location.href = `http://localhost:8024/dummy?id=set`;

It doesn't work.
So I compare the logpoint1 and logpoint2, however I can't find any difference.
Where is the problem ?



What is in the console. Also are you opening the window from a page that is loaded with the origin http://localhost:8024 ?

From what you've written the only difference seems to be that you switch from changing just search parameters to changing a path + search parameters. Could you explain what's not working? What does the console output when you call console.log(window.myWin) after switching to http://localhost:8024/dummy?id=set?

@mplungjan my page is http://localhost:8023, these two are different application.

So that is the reason. They need to come from same origin

mmm, this could be controld ? like Access-Control-Allow-Origin or is it impossible?

And mysteriously, 3rd line of firsts script window.myWin.location.href = http://localhost:8024/?id=test2; this works, so until the control(focus()?) was finished, location.href for popup window works.
